# PHP code displaying as plain text and isset($_POST) not working

Tags: php, isset

I've been trying to use PHP to connect to MySQL and display some data. I'm completely new to this. I read up on the subject mainly from w3schools, and a few other site found on Google.
However I'm having 2 problems 1st, the PHP code starting after

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Passengers_On_Flight");
```

is being displayed as plain text.

The other problem is that the it always happens even when a form has not been submitted which leads me to believe that form some reason the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` is not being evaluated correctly. I've found other questions where people have the problem that its never evaluating true but not that it always evaluates true.

I did a PHP -v on my server to ensure php5 is installed, I also did this: http://www.gilesorr.com/papers/PHP/x37.html

both showed that PHP was in fact installed and working. I've searched but can't seem to figure out the problem.

Here is my HTML with PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cobraStyle.css">
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Cobra</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>
            Cobra Airlines
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="viewFlights.html">Check Flights</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Administration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        <h2>
        Flights heading
        </h2>
        <?php
        if($_POST['submit'])
        {
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","qwerty");
        if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("Cobra_Airlines", $con);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Passengers_On_Flight");

        echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>Fligh Number</th>
            <th>Departure Date</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Passenger Number</th>
            </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['FlightNum'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Departure_Date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['PassengerNum'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        mysql_close($con);
    }
?>
<p>
<form name="input" action="viewFlights.html" method="post">
    Flight Number: <input type="text" name="flight">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Copyright © Cobra Air, 2012
</div>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is the updated PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cobraStyle.css">
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Cobra</TITLE>
   </HEAD>

   <BODY>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
                <h1>
                    Cobra Airlines
                </h1>
            </div>

        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="viewFlights.html">Check Flights</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Administration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <h2>
                Flights heading
            </h2>

            <?php


                    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","qwerty");
                    if (!$con)
                    {
                        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    mysql_select_db("Cobra_Airlines", $con);

                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Passengers_On_Flight");

                    echo 
                    "<table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Fligh Number</th>
                        <th>Departure Date</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Passenger Number</th>
                    </tr>";

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['FlightNum'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Departure_Date'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['PassengerNum'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";

                    endwhile;
                    echo "</table>";

                    mysql_close($con);

            ?>

            <p>
                <form name="input" action="viewFlights.php" method="post">
                    Flight Number: <input type="text" name="flight">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
                </form>
            </p>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            Copyright © Cobra Air, 2012
        </div>
</div>

   </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: action="viewFlights.html" are you parsing html as PHP?

Comment: in addition mysql_ is now being phased out, you should instead use mysqli.

Comment: action="viewFlights.html" is outside the php tags, I believe

Comment: No it's nothing to do with the php tags. Your pages are .html, they are not parsed as php unless you explicitly tell your server to do that.

Comment: Don't read w3schools: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is they are html files not php `viewFlights.html` and `x37.html` won't parse as PHP unless your server is told .html is supposed to.

Change their file names to `.php`, i.e. `viewFlights.php` and `x37.php` (and update your form action to viewFlights.php).

You should change `if ($_POST['submit'])` to `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` to avoid and Undefined index error.

**Aside...**

When you've dealt with that, I can never fathom why people do this where white-space isn't important.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FlightNum'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Departure_Date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['PassengerNum'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

just

```
echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['FlightNum'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['Departure_Date'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['Last_Name'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['PassengerNum'] . "</td>
    </tr>
";
```

**EDIT**

Answer to second problem, while(){} has been changed to while():endwhile but the colon is missing. Needs to be

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
```

Comment: Ok thanks i tried it. However now I get:

HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

is this because there is something wrong with my php code?

Comment: You will have an undefined index "submit" because you're not checking for it but that shouldn't cause a 500. Does the test page work?

Comment: but has the 500 gone? If not, edit your question and post the new code underneath the old.

Comment: other than cahnging the xtension to .php and edit action="viewFlights.html" to action="viewFlights.php" nothing has changed. Do you still want me to post the code? Also I removed my php code so it only contain am echo, it worked then I added if($_POST['submit']) as a condition to echo. and it agve a 500 error again so i guess the problem is with that line.

Comment: ok, you've changed your while(){} to while():endwhile, put it back to braces or add a colon after the condition, e.g. while(condition):

Comment: WOW! Man that was it. Everything is working now. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by plain text? if you are trying to pull records unless its a password etc... shouldnt it be fine?

by you `$_POST`ing the submit value, you are just pushing it no where.

you should be `$_POST`ing the Flight number like:  `if($_POST['flight'])`

you are missing a chunk of programming to pull the records too.

i suggest you plan the process, before you code.

also, the structure of your mysql connection is poor, keep ONE persistent connection in an external directory, until you are ready to close it, it uses less resources.

(../Connections/config.php)

`$pcon = mysql_pconnect('','','')`

`mysql_select_db('', $pcon)`

dont forget to change the page to a .php extension not .html!!

Comment: by plain text I mean rather than the records on the data base I get

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['FlightNum'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Departure_Date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['PassengerNum'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        mysql_close($con);